# How can I mandate one class will hold One type of inner object

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a requirement like from different type of objects I need to create AlertModelWrapper object. For this I can pass student only to StudentAlertGenerator, and teacher only to TeacherAlertGenerator. What should be the interface method here? If i take object i can't mandate student can have only Student type. Where my design lags?

```
public class StudentAlertGenerator : IAlertGeneratorType
{
  private readonly IDateTransformationService transformationService
  public StudentAlertGenerator(IDateTransformationService transformationService)
  {
     this.trnasformationservice =transformationservice
  }
  public AlertModelWrapper CreateAlertTypeModel(Student student)
  {
    return new AlertModelWrapper ()
    {
        ID= "std_"+student.Id,
        AlertModel = new AlertModel () { alertDetails=student.Name + "has an alert on " +transformationService.Transform(DateTime.Now())}
    };
  }
}
```

and teacher alertGeneratory as follows

```
public class TeacherAlertGenerator : IAlertGeneratorType
{
  private readonly IDateTransformationService transformationService
  public StudentAlertGenerator(IDateTransformationService transformationService)
  {
     this.trnasformationservice =transformationservice
  }
  public AlertModelWrapper CreateAlertTypeModel(Teacher teacher)
  {
    return new AlertModelWrapper ()
    {
        ID= "tea_"+teacher.Id,
        AlertModel = new AlertModel () { alertDetails=teacher.Name + "has an alert on " +transformationService.Transform(DateTime.Now())}
    };
  }
}
```

----Edit----
My basic requirement is I need to call it in an iterator

```
List<IAlertGeneratorType> alerts=DecissionEngine.GetAlerts();
foreach(var alert in alerts)
{
   //make object x from decission engine response(it will tell what type of object and id)
   //api push on alert.CreateAlertTypeModel(x);
}
```

Here i should be able to pass x. But x's type I dont know now. So what should be my interface? Or is this a design issue?

Comment: If you don't know what problem you have SO can't help you. There is no way by looking at the code (that at least look correct) to know what you want this code to look like. Please [edit] post to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My english may bit bad... Sorry for that. My query was what should be interface IAlertGeneratorType here? I need to use this in an iterator which calls IAlertGeneratorType.CreateAlertTypeModel()

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to declare interface method which can work with Student and Teacher classes.

For that you can create interface - for example IPerson - with properties Id and Name:

```
public interface IPerson
{
     int Id {get;set;}
     string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you should implement that interface with you classes:

```
public class Student: IPerson
public class Teacher: IPerson
```

After that you can change parameter type in your method:

```
public interface IAlertGeneratorType
{
    public AlertModelWrapper CreateAlertTypeModel(IPerson person);
}
```

This method will work with both of classes: Student and Teacher

```
public class AlertGenerator : IAlertGeneratorType
{
  private readonly IDateTransformationService transformationService
  public StudentAlertGenerator(IDateTransformationService transformationService)
  {
     this.trnasformationservice =transformationservice
  }
  public AlertModelWrapper CreateAlertTypeModel(IPerson person)
  {
    return new AlertModelWrapper ()
    {
        ID= "tea_"+person.Id,
        AlertModel = new AlertModel () { alertDetails=person.Name + "has an alert on " +transformationService.Transform(DateTime.Now())}
    };
  }
}
```

Example:

```
   var generator = new AlertGenerator();
    var teacher = new Teacher();
    var student = new Student();
    generator.CreateAlertTypeModel(teacher);
    generator.CreateAlertTypeModel(student);
```

Comment: I Appreciate your effort. This is normal way of implementation. My situation is bit different. I have an iterator which will call webapi to push alerts. That part works fine. It needs a list of alert

To generate that I will have a hetrogenious data objects. One may school, second may teacher, third may student.

I have a decission engine which will generate which all alerts to generate. The above TeacherAlertGenerator, StudentAlertGenerator are output of that engine. Each's responsibility to make alert for its specific type. Further iterator should take care

Comment: It hard to understand. Maybe what are you are looking for its a fabric pattern?